# Is "to put in" a phrasal verb here?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

> If I had the pen of a Napier, or a Bell's Life, I should like to
>   describe this combat properly. It was the last charge of the
>   Guard—(that is, it would have been, only Waterloo had not yet taken
>   place)—it was Ney's column breasting the hill of La Haye Sainte,
>   bristling with ten thousand bayonets, and crowned with twenty
>   eagles—it was the shout of the beef-eating British, as leaping down
>   the hill they rushed to hug the enemy in the savage arms of battle—in
>   other words, Cuff coming up full of pluck, but quite reeling and
>   groggy, the Fig-merchant **put in** his left as usual **on his
>   adversary's nose**, and sent him down for the last time.

(from *Vanity Fair*)

And if so, what does it mean?

Couldn't Thackeray have just said "[he] put ... on his adversary's nose?"

Why the need for "in"?

Comment: I can't find an authority recognising this usage, but 'He put in a couple of handy left jabs' rings a few bells from when my grandfather used to watch boxing on TV many years ago. Phrasal verb? 'Put in' is certainly pretty unitary here. 'He landed ... ' would work as a more formal paraphrase.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There must me some dictionary that has this usage recorded. The usual dictionaries give the phrasal verb "to put [something] in," of course, but none of the meanings listed there seems to be a perfect fit for this one here. I know it is "old" English, but I nevertheless want to know what it means exactly, dictionary-wise. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: There are few obvious hits turning up in reasonable Google searches. I've found one for "He put in a couple of shots where the goalie got the ball", which is closer than the common 'Jack put in a couple of hours on the garden' etc.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb "put in" is somewhat similar to a usage like

> He put in nine hours at work today

in the sense of making a contribution, but context makes it clear it's not helping an adversary, it's making an effort to help his own side.

It's also a bit like "to put in" a piece that fits in to e.g. a puzzle, or in this case a fist that fits in to adversary's face.